# Send variable from C# to php for MySQL (Unity)

Tags: c#, php, mysql, sqlite, unity-game-engine

i'm new to MySQL system. I have to store in a database:

Username;
Score;
Resources.

For send username, score and resources i don't have any problems but whene i try to get resources from database i have this error:

```
</style>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Bad request!</h1>
<p>


Your browser (or proxy) sent a request that
this server could not understand.

</p>
<p>
If you think this is a server error, please contact
the <a href="mailto:postmaster@localhost">webmaster</a>.

</p>

<h2>Error 400</h2>
<address>
<a href="/">localhost</a><br />
<span>Apache/2.4.25 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2j PHP/7.1.1</span>
</address>
</body>
</html>


UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
<SetPlayerName>c__Iterator1:MoveNext() (at       Assets/Scripts/DataBase/MySQL/DBLoader.cs:67)
UnityEngine.SetupCoroutine:InvokeMoveNext(IEnumerator, IntPtr)
```

This is my php file:

```
<?php

    $servername = "host";
    $username    = "name";
    $password    = "";
    $dbname        = "game_name";

    $coinsname     = (isset($_REQUEST['coinsnameGet']) ? $_REQUEST['coinsnameGet'] : null);

    //Create Connection
    $connection = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    //Check Connection
    if(!$connection) {
        die("Connection Failed. " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }

    $sql = "SELECT Coins FROM score WHERE Name = '" . $coinsname . "'";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_BOTH) {
        echo $row['Coins'];
    }
?>
```

I have to check if name is == to local database name then get resources.
The local db is made with sqlite.

And this is my connected class:

```
private DataBase dbLocal;

    WWW userData;
    WWW scoreData;
    WWW coinsData;

    public Text Coins;

    private string[] dbUsers;
    private string[] dbScores;

    private string dbCoins;

    private string postCoinsData = "http://host/game_name/UsercoinsData.php";

    public GameObject scorePrefab;
    public Transform scoreParent;

    public GameObject rankValue;
    public GameObject nameValue;
    public GameObject scoreValue;

    // Use this for initialization
    IEnumerator Start () {

        dbLocal = (DataBase)FindObjectOfType(typeof(DataBase));

        userData = new WWW("http://host/game_name/UsernameData.php");
        scoreData = new WWW("http://host/game_name/UserscoreData.php");

        yield return userData;
        yield return scoreData;

        string textUserData = userData.text;
        dbUsers = textUserData.Split(';');

        string textScoreData = scoreData.text;
        dbScores = textScoreData.Split(';');

        scoreParent.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);

        dbLocal.Connection();

        StartCoroutine(SetPlayerName());
        GenerateScore();
    }

    IEnumerator SetPlayerName()
    {
        string setName = postCoinsData + "coinsnameGet = " + WWW.EscapeURL(dbLocal.GetName());
        WWW dataCoins = new WWW(setName);

        Debug.Log(dbLocal.GetName());

        yield return dataCoins;

        string textDataCoins = dataCoins.text;
        Coins.text = textDataCoins;
        Debug.Log(Coins.text); //This log the error
    }
```

If i change this:

```
$sql = "SELECT Coins FROM score WHERE Name = '" . $coinsname . "'";
```

with this:

```
$sql = "SELECT Coins FROM score WHERE Name = 'PlayerName'";
```

In brower i see the score.

Thx in advance!

Comment: You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of concatenating your queries. Specially since you're not escaping the user inputs at all! It's not just a security concern, but if the input contains, for example, a `'`-character or a backslash, your query will fail.

Answer (score 1):

Your php will never find the `$_REQUEST['coinsnameGet']` because you're creating the URL like this:

```
string setName = postCoinsData + "coinsnameGet = " + WWW.EscapeURL(dbLocal.GetName());
```

which will look something like:

> http://host/game_name/UsercoinsData.phpcoinsnameGet = PlayerName

but should look like

> http://host/game_name/UsercoinsData.php?coinsnameGet=PlayerName

Not entirely sure if this is what's causing your issues or if it's a copy-paste error, but if it is, your code should be changed to:

```
string setName = postCoinsData + "?coinsnameGet=" + WWW.EscapeURL(dbLocal.GetName());
```